# Safari 11 Status Bar

Tags: safari

I am relatively new to Mac, and I am trying to get used to using Safari, after using Chrome for years.

I'll click on a link in Chrome, and see a status saying "**Loading...**" or something to that effect.  But with Safari, I don't get any status messages.  I've turned on the status bar in the **View** menu.  Should I expect to see these kinds of messages in the status bar?

I am on the latest OS (High Sierra).

Answer (score 1):

There should be a small blue bar in the bottom of the URL field that indicates that a page is loading.

It should look like this:

[image: Safari loading page]

I'm not aware of any loading indicator in the Status Bar. As far as I know, the status bar only display the link's full address when holding the pointer over a link ([Apple Support Article](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/customize-the-safari-window-ibrw1012/mac)).